# Bootstrap Navbar wrapping to second line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am working on a nav bar with Bootstrap and my condensed menu always is wrapping to a new line, even when there should be space on the line above.  This started occurring when added the logo (in place of the red block).

[image: Logo with navbar wrapping]

```css
.logo-scrollbar {
  width: 30%;  
}

#mainNav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #12AEA1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}



#mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link,
#mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link:focus {
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #212529;
}



@media (min-width: 992px) {

  #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }

  #mainNav.navbar-shrink {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
    background-color: #fff;
  }


}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
            <img src="https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" class="logo-scrollbar" alt="logo image">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What would be causing this?

Comment: I edited your question adding a snippet using your code and it does not happen what you describe in your question,  can you add a functional example that reflects your problem?

Comment: @Yandy_Viera I added a legitimate image so it now shows the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a problem with setting the width of the img `.logo-scrollbar` in percent inside the `a .navbar-brand` to fix it you have 3 options

1- Overwrite the display of `.navbar-brand` to `display: contents;`

```css
.logo-scrollbar {
  width: 30%;  
}

#mainNav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #12AEA1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  display: contents;       /* add this */
}



#mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link,
#mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link:focus {
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #212529;
}



@media (min-width: 992px) {

  #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }

  #mainNav.navbar-shrink {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
    background-color: #fff;
  }


}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
            <img src="https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" class="logo-scrollbar" alt="logo image">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

2- Set the width of `.logo-scrollbar` in `px`

3- Set the `width: 30%;` to `.navbar-brand` and `width:100%` to `.logo-scrollbar`